# Using ntwitter with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble getting ntwitter to work with node.js, I am most likely installing something incorrectly. I have node.js working with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:1337/`, I am met with a Hello World! But that is not the problem. Now I attempt to use ntwitter to connect to twitters streaming API.

First I attempt to install ntwitter using npm on node.js command line, but that installs it in my user folder.

> npm install ntwitter
>
> keygrip@0.2.4 install C:\Users\Corey\node_modules\ntwitter\node_modules

I copied these files into my nodejs directory, C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules, and then tried to execute the following code

```
var twitter = require('ntwitter');

var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: '2RsSvO6eREnV6P5MsSPhQ',
    consumer_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    access_token_key: '2353803367-TLCjurDBKiRVLiqFjX4ttktC8nita4kpG0aAgrV',
    access_token_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000');

var sw='-73.68,42.72', ne='-73.67,42.73';
twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'locations':sw +','+ne},
    function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

And node.js throws the error "Cannot find module 'ntwitter'".

Does anyone know how to fix this/install ntwitter and other node packets properly

If it helps, I am running 64-bit Windows 7

Comment: Where does this script live? The `node_modules` folder that contains `ntwitter` should live at the same level as the script.

Comment: So I should put the script in the `node_modules` folder? Right now the script is sitting in the directory above it.

Comment: No, the script and the `node_moduels` folder should themselves be in the same folder. Inside `node_modules`, there should be the `ntwitter` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to keep track of modules is defining dependencies in [package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html)

```
{
  "name": "nodeapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "ntwitter":"*",
    ...
  }
}
```

Then run **npm install** to install all needed packages at once